# Loop through set of elements and add proper value from different array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through a set of elements of the same class and add a matching value from different array but something is wrong. Here is a code sample:

```
var targetElements = $('.selected');
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]; 

//this works but it ads the same value
for(j=0; j < targetElements.length; j++){
     targetElements.html(array1[j]);         
}

//if I try this, it does not work and I get error
//TypeError: targetElements[j].html is not a function
for(j=0; j < targetElements.length; j++){
     targetElements[j].html(array1[j]);         
}
```

Why am I getting a TypeError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `each()`. to iterate through the elements and `this` to target each respective jQuery object/element. The issue is that `.html()` is a jQuery method and you are trying to execute that on a pure DOM element.

```
targetElements.each(function( ) {
  $(this).html(array1[k]);
});
```

or

```
for(j=0; j < targetElements.length; j++){
     $(targetElements[j]).html(array1[j]);         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method:

```js
var targetElements = $('.selected');
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]; 

for(j = 0; j < targetElements.length; j++) {
  targetElements.eq(j).html(array1[j]);         
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="selected"></p>
<p class="selected"></p>
<p class="selected"></p>
```

---

You can avoid the loop altogether by setting the `html()` of the selection based on its index:

```js
var targetElements = $('.selected');
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]; 

targetElements.html(function(idx) {
  return array1[idx];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="selected"></p>
<p class="selected"></p>
<p class="selected"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `targetElements` is a jQuery object, more or less a wrapper around an array of DOM elements. By using the array notation `targetElements[j]` you get an item from the array, but that element does not have the jQuery wrapper, and so it does not have the jQuery `.html()` method, hence the error.

You can wrap the item and make it a jQuery object again by putting `$()` around it, like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < targetElements.length; j++) {
    $(targetElements[j]).html(array1[j]);         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `targetElements` is assigned a jQuery object. jQuery objects acts as collections of DOM nodes. The DOM nodes themselves do not understand jQuery calls, only the wrapping jQuery object does. By using array indicing you are accessing one of those DOM nodes directly and then attempting to call a function (`.html()`) that doesn't exist on DOM nodes. You'll need to re-wrap that DOM node in a jQuery object to get back the functionality you want as in `$(targetElements[j])`:

```
for(j=0; j < targetElements.length; j++){
  $(targetElements[j]).html(array1[j]);         
}
```

(While primarily used to select elements out of a document, [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) has a lot of capabilities tied to it. Read [more about it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) the documentation.)

Even better, use jQuery's collection tools to loop through the jQuery object, in this case [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
targetElements.each(function(i, v) {
  $(v).html(array1[i]);
});
```